# DialogFlow quickstart example in java not working for me

Tags: java, dialogflow-es

I am trying to run the DialogFlow Quick start sample to start using its functions. But it doesn't work for me. I have added the environment variable to login. Now, on the line:

`DetectIntentResponse response = sessionsClient.detectIntent (session, queryInput);`

it takes a lot of time and then fails. I am using Eclipse in debug mode.

```
    Suppressed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.sslReadErrorResult(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1288)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1249)
        ... 24 more
```

my code:

```
// DialogFlow API Detect Intent sample with text inputs.
      public static Map<String, QueryResult> detectIntentTexts(String projectId, List<String> texts, String sessionId, String languageCode)  throws IOException, ApiException {
          
        Map<String, QueryResult> queryResults = Maps.newHashMap();
        // Instantiates a client
        try (SessionsClient sessionsClient = SessionsClient.create()) {
          // Set the session name using the sessionId (UUID) and projectID (my-project-id)
          SessionName session = SessionName.of(projectId, sessionId);
          System.out.println("Session Path: " + session.toString());

          // Detect intents for each text input
          for (String text : texts) {
            // Set the text (hello) and language code (en-US) for the query
            TextInput.Builder textInput =
                TextInput.newBuilder().setText(text).setLanguageCode(languageCode);

            // Build the query with the TextInput
            QueryInput queryInput = QueryInput.newBuilder().setText(textInput).build();

            // Performs the detect intent request
            DetectIntentResponse response = sessionsClient.detectIntent(session, queryInput);

            // Display the query result
            QueryResult queryResult = response.getQueryResult();
            
            System.out.println("====================");
            System.out.format("Query Text: '%s'\n", queryResult.getQueryText());
            System.out.format(
                "Detected Intent: %s (confidence: %f)\n",
                queryResult.getIntent().getDisplayName(), queryResult.getIntentDetectionConfidence());
            System.out.format(
                "Fulfillment Text: '%s'\n",
                queryResult.getFulfillmentMessagesCount() > 0
                    ? queryResult.getFulfillmentMessages(0).getText()
                    : "Triggered Default Fallback Intent");

            queryResults.put(text, queryResult);
          }
        }
        return queryResults;
      }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you update your question to include the link to the quick start example that you're trying to use? It would be useful to see what other steps they require before running the code.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem. the code was fine. the problem ocurred by the proxy. my computer did'n have permission to access at all google resources.